# How do I rephrase "As a newbie, let me give you some advice" where "newbie" applies to the listener?

Tags: dangling-modifiers

I've come across phrases like the following.

> As a veteran, let me give you some advice. (I am a veteran, so I can offer some advice.)

Usually, "veteran" refers to the speaker.

Sometimes, I hastily construct a similar phrase, with "newbie" instead of "veteran", but with the person spoken to being the newbie.

> As a newbie, let me give you some advice. (You are the newbie, so I can offer some advice.)

This version strikes me as weird, and I usually rephrase. Could it ever be used in the second fashion, or is it strictly the first case (the noun referring to the speaker)?

I tried to rephrase to remove ambiguity:

> - Seeing that you are a newbie, let me give you some advice.
> - In light of you being a newbie, let me give you some advice.
> - It seems like you are a newbie, so let me give you some advice.

However, I feel these can be improved. The first two seem a bit condescending, and the third just makes an assumption where the original phrase states a fact.

Comment: Let me give you, a newbie, some advice.

Comment: Thanks, that's an option, but also slightly condescending I think. I'd put it in the list of possibilities that I'm not perfectly happy with. I generally have the feeling that the more sophisticated the language is, the more condescending it appears for this phrase, could be just me though. But I was wondering whether there was a simple, snappy way to put this.

Comment: It's a [dangling modifier](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/dangling_modifiers_and_how_to_correct_them.html), a grammatical structure ambiguous by nature. I think you'll be able to help yourself.

Comment: The main issue is how to label people without offending. No good. Better to suggest I did something foolish than to call me a fool. "You may be new, so let me ..." Also, the misplaced modifier is here:  "As a **newbie**, let **me** give you some advice." Better: As a newbie, would **you** appreciate some advice or rather not?"

Comment: "Since you're a newbie ..."

Comment: @niamulbengali Thanks, that's helpful. I've seen these dangling modifiers before, but didn't think they'd apply for this case. Thanks for reminding me that they are generally ambiguous and shouldn't be used at all.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Good point. The reason why the first one works in a non-condescending way and the second one doesn't (assuming for a second that the second one was proper English) is probably that we shift the label from ourselves to someone else. "As an idiot, let me tell you how to not do it" is self-deprecating and therefore not condescending. If we switched this, we'd call the other person an idiot and there would be no way to phrase this in a softer way without causing insult. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Also the point of the misplaced modifier is a very good tip. I wonder though. If this is a case of a dangling modifier, then it should be generally avoided because it introduces ambiguity. I can see that in other cases of dangling modifiers, but here it seems pretty straightforward. Is there really ambiguity in this specific example?

Comment: If the references are clear, it's just a modifier. When it *dangles*, it becomes ambiguous—these are the ones you should avoid. The first one is an example of correct usage, and the second one of incorrect usage; so I wouldn't say "Don't use these phrases at all."